# Kafka consumer error handling

Tags: java, spring-kafka

I am new to Kafka. We are doing Kafka integration with our Application. The problem is that, while consuming suppose if some error occurs in processing a particular record then how to handle this scenario.

I am using spring kafka.

If retry of that particular record is the solution, then I want to do it separately. Eg if I have offset 1 to 10 and offset 4 record gives error, then offset 5 to 10 gets consumed normally and after 10 min record at offset 4 gets retried.

I checked a few links but they are of little help.

Any leads/solutions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: If retry of that particular record is the solution, then I want to do it separately. Eg if I have offset 1 to 10 and offset 4 record gives error, then offset 5 to 10 gets consumed normally and after 10 min record at offset 4 gets retried.

Comment: Please, move your comment as an EDIT to the question. Not enough info BTW. You can start from the Reference Manual: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.1.1.RELEASE/reference/html/

Answer (score 1):

You have to save the messages that failed to a diferent channel, may add metadata like the reason of failure. Then at some point reprocess that channel of failed messages. A different approach is to rewind the offset but I think it is more difficul because you need to process only the messages that failed.